# AWS SNS - How to parse this json object with a equal sign?

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS Sns to send a push notification to the user using the device's `endpoint arn`.

I have a `FirebaseMessagingService` that listens to incoming push messages from Sns.

However the messages that are coming from SNS contain a JSON format I've never seen before.

It has a equal sign in the middle of the String.

```
{message=hello there test message}
```

How can I correctly parse this String into an object class?

I've tried using the GSON library but i'm getting an error and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`:

```
public class FirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
            PrintMessage message = gson.fromJson(params.get("message"), PrintMessage.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class PrintMessage {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```